# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)}$ centered at $z = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

practice problem got us stuck -- please help us!!! Thank you..<3

Find a Laurent series for $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)}$ centered at $z=1$ and specify the region in which it converges.

What we did was looking at the region $|z-1|>2$, where the function is holomorphic. For this region we can use the formulae for Laurent series and $c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{(w-1)^{-k-2}}{w+1}dw$. We are stuck at for which values of $k$ the integral goes to 0 and for other values of $k$ how to evaluate the integral...

Thanks!

Comment: For $k>-2$, how can we evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 3):

For $\;\,z\,\;$ "close enough" to $\,1\,$ :

$$\frac1{(z-1)(z+1)}=\frac1{z-1}\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}2}=$$

$$=\frac1{2(z-1)}\left(1-\frac{z-1}2+\frac{(z-1)^2}4-\frac{(z-1)^3}8+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac1{2(z-1)}-\frac14+\frac{z-1}8-\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: partial fractions and geometric series.